# Errors in eclipse oxygen

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Several weeks ago I switched to Eclipse Oxygen and started getting errors as below.

> Version 8.0 of project facet jst.appclient does not exist.
>
> Version 8.0 of project facet jst.ear does not exist.

They do not seem to impact development of my apps running from Eclipse at least for now but I it makes me nervous. Does anybody know if there is a remedy?

**Here is the record of this error:**

> eclipse.buildId=4.7.1.M20171009-0410 java.version=1.8.0_144
>   java.vendor=Oracle Corporation BootLoader constants: OS=win32,
>   ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US Framework arguments:  -product
>   org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product Command-line arguments:  -os win32
>   -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
>
> org.eclipse.jst.j2ee Error Mon Oct 16 09:42:34 CEST 2017 Version 8.0
>   of project facet jst.appclient does not exist.
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Version 8.0 of project facet
>   jst.appclient does not exist.     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.util.internal.Versionable.getVersion(Versionable.java:80)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.ProjectFacet.getVersion(ProjectFacet.java:1)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.model.J2EEModelProviderRegistry.readElement(J2EEModelProviderRegistry.java:85)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.common.core.util.RegistryReader.internalReadElement(RegistryReader.java:81)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.common.core.util.RegistryReader.readRegistry(RegistryReader.java:122)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.model.J2EEModelProviderRegistry.getInstance(J2EEModelProviderRegistry.java:43)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.model.ModelProviderManager.initProviders(ModelProviderManager.java:262)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.model.ModelProviderManager.getProviders(ModelProviderManager.java:338)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.model.ModelProviderManager.getProvider(ModelProviderManager.java:223)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.model.ModelProviderManager.getModelProvider(ModelProviderManager.java:93)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.model.ModelProviderManager.getModelProvider(ModelProviderManager.java:281)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jst.jee.ui.internal.navigator.JEE5ContentProvider.getCachedModelProvider(JEE5ContentProvider.java:76)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jst.jee.ui.internal.navigator.Web25ContentProvider.getNewContentProviderInstance(Web25ContentProvider.java:69)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jst.jee.ui.internal.navigator.LoadingJeeDDJob.run(LoadingJeeDDJob.java:50)
>     at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
>
> org.eclipse.jst.j2ee Error Mon Oct 16 09:42:34 CEST 2017 Version 8.0
>   of project facet jst.ear does not exist.
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Version 8.0 of project facet
>   jst.ear does not exist.   at
>   org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.util.internal.Versionable.getVersion(Versionable.java:80)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.ProjectFacet.getVersion(ProjectFacet.java:1)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.model.J2EEModelProviderRegistry.readElement(J2EEModelProviderRegistry.java:85)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.common.core.util.RegistryReader.internalReadElement(RegistryReader.java:81)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.common.core.util.RegistryReader.readRegistry(RegistryReader.java:122)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.model.J2EEModelProviderRegistry.getInstance(J2EEModelProviderRegistry.java:43)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.model.ModelProviderManager.initProviders(ModelProviderManager.java:262)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.model.ModelProviderManager.getProviders(ModelProviderManager.java:338)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.model.ModelProviderManager.getProvider(ModelProviderManager.java:223)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.model.ModelProviderManager.getModelProvider(ModelProviderManager.java:93)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.model.ModelProviderManager.getModelProvider(ModelProviderManager.java:281)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jst.jee.ui.internal.navigator.JEE5ContentProvider.getCachedModelProvider(JEE5ContentProvider.java:76)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jst.jee.ui.internal.navigator.Web25ContentProvider.getNewContentProviderInstance(Web25ContentProvider.java:69)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jst.jee.ui.internal.navigator.LoadingJeeDDJob.run(LoadingJeeDDJob.java:50)
>     at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)

Comment: When and where do you get this error?

Comment: The error appears in ErrorLog view when I launch Eclipse

Comment: I also get this error when I create a maven project with the org.glassfish.jersey.archetype jersey-webapp-quickstart (v 2.26)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a known bug in Oxygen.1A.  Bug report in Eclipse here:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=526543
and per that page it is supposedly fixed in "Oxygen.2 RC1" available November 17.  Unfortunately I could not find a workaround to this benign pain and will suffer with it until Oxygen.2 is rolled later this month.